# Change background-color of a table on random with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to attach a color-changing property to a table background.

```
var bakgrunnFarge=new Array("#CCFFCC", "#FFCCCC")
document.getElementById("change_color").style.background=bakgrunnFarge[Math.floor(Math.random()*bakgrunnFarge.length)]

<table class="change_color" name="change_color" id="change_color">
```

But I just can't get it to work, any help would be much appreciated.
In advance, thank you

Comment: Works in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJLSf/)

Comment: yeah, as usual my problem was caused by lack of patience and a quite slow sense of logic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your javascript UNDER your elements (your table):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random background-color</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="change_color" name="change_color" id="change_color">
        <tr>
            <td>lorem</td>
            <td>lorem</td>
            <td>lorem</td>
            <td>lorem</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>lorem</td>
            <td>lorem</td>
            <td>lorem</td>
            <td>lorem</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bakgrunnFarge=new Array("#CCFFCC", "#FFCCCC");
    window.document.getElementById("change_color").style.background=bakgrunnFarge[Math.floor(Math.random()*bakgrunnFarge.length)]
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick... forgot about the logical read-order, my bad :P

Answer (score 2):

The DOM hasn't loaded yet. You can do something like this...

```
document.body.onload = function() {
    var bakgrunnFarge=new Array("#CCFFCC", "#FFCCCC")
    document.getElementById("change_color").style.background=bakgrunnFarge[Math.floor(Math.random()*bakgrunnFarge.length)]
}
```

Or place a handler in your body tag:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">Stuff</body>
```

Ooorr you can listen to the event `DOMContentLoaded` as so:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var bakgrunnFarge=new Array("#CCFFCC", "#FFCCCC")
    document.getElementById("change_color").style.background=bakgrunnFarge[Math.floor(Math.random()*bakgrunnFarge.length)]
});
```